# How to show that this norm is a metric?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

For a Normed vector space $(V,\|{\cdot}\|)$:

I know that $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$ is a metric since it satisfies all the rules:

1. $d(x,x)\geq 0$ and $d(x,y)=0 \iff x=y=0$
2. $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$
3. $d(x,y)\leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)$

Now the question is for

$d(x,y):= \|x-y\|$ if $\exists a\in \mathbb{R}:x=ay$ and $d(x,y)=\|x\|+\|y\|$ if not.

My question is do I need the Minkowski inequality to show the triangular inequality for this Metrik or is there a way w/o using it?

Comment: What space do $x$ and $y$ live in?

Comment: Have added: normed vectorspace.

Comment: I guess you mean a finite dimensional normed vector space over $\mathbb{R}$?